# SharePoint 2010: Breaking role inheritance with ECMAScript

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ecmascript-5

Does anybody know how to break role inheritance on a web (i.e. stop inheriting permissions from its parent) using ECMAscript?

This is the JavaScript code that I am trying to use, but I get a runtime error stating that the properties have not been properly initialised:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
clientContext.load(web);

if (!web.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments()) {
    web.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);
}
```

Interestingly, if I interogate the web object during debugging, I can see that both the hasUniqueRoleAssignments property and breakRoleInheritance function DO in fact exist. In addition, MSDN states that both these members are available on the [SP.SecurableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409343.aspx) class -- I would've assumed that both a Web or List would inherit from this class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Retrieving a Client Object Does Not Retrieve All Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534974.aspx), you will need to call executeQueryAsync and use get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments inside a delegate function:

> In the server object model, when you return an SPWeb object, all of its properties become available for use in code. But to improve performance in the client object model, when you return a Web object certain properties are not included, and you must explicitly retrieve them. For example, the Web class inherits the HasUniqueRoleAssignments property from the SecurableObject class, but when you return a Web object this property is not retrieved by default.

Comment: The example code in the article you provided was exactly what I needed -- right down to the actual property I was after. Many thanks Rich.